# Populate knockout view model from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I'm in the process of replacing one hell of a lot of javascript/jquery code with knockoutjs and I'm trying to figure out the best way forward. I have no time to replace everything at the same time so I will have to integrate the knockout logic with the existing javascript...

Is there a way to populate a knockout view model from javascript which is not called from a data-bind attribute? Any help would be nice since I've not been able to find this anywhere else (at least not anything that worked).

I know what I'm mentioning here isn't the "correct" way of doing things, but I'm trying to migrate parts of the javascript code... Doing it all in one go isn't an option at the moment.

(using knockout 3.2)

Edit:
Typically the existing javascript does something like:

```
$('#productlist').append(productItemHtmlCode);
```

And I would rather have it do something like:

```
ViewModel.productList.push(productItemObject);
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  Are you looking for a way to make observables out of your data?  Or are you asking for to 'wrap' the current code in a KO viewmodel?  Or both?  Maybe a bit of an example would help.

Comment: The existing javascript logic modifies the DOM in lots of ways and by way of upgrading the current logic to knockout I would like it to modify the ViewModel instead... if at all possible :)

Comment: So basically, from the example you provided, you want to temporarily reverse Knockout's working from *updating the view from the model* to *updating the model **partially** from the view*? I don't think that is possible. Instead, I would start considering my jQuery code as components and progressively convert each piece into knockout code

Comment: Too bad... would be nice while im doing my refactoring

Comment: It would be possible however, to, eg. set a Knockout observable to watch the `innerHTML` of the `#productList` div, and return a computed observable containing data retrieved from the DOM in an object... But I don't know how well that would serve your purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, currently you have something like this:

```
<div id='myDiv'>
       current status is: <span id='statusSpan'>Active</span>
</div>
```

with some corresponding javascript that might be something like:

```
function toggleStatus() {
    var s= document.getElementById('statusSpan');
    s.innerHTML = s.innerHTML == 'Active' ? 'Inactive' : 'Active';
}
```

And you want to change it so that the javascript is updating the viewmodel rather than manipulating the DOM?

```
var app = (function() {

    var vm = {
        statusText: ko.observable('Active'),
        toggleStatus: toggleStatus
    }

    return vm

    function toggleStatus() {
        vm.statusText = vm.statusText == 'Active' ? 'Inactive' : 'Active';
    }

}) ();

ko.applyBindings(app,document.getElementById('myDiv'));
```

And then the html would be

```
<div id='myDiv'>
       current status is: <span id='statusSpan' data-bind="text: statusText"></span>
</div>
```

If that's what you're talking about, that's what Knockout is designed for.  The javascript updates the viewmodel, knockout manipulates the DOM.

The example you give is easy to represent in Knockout.

the HTML:

```
<div>
       <table data-bind="foreach: products">
            <tr>
                 <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
                 <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                 <td data-bind="text: category"></td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

and in the viewmodel:

```
vm = {
    products: ko.observableArray(),  // empty array to start
    addProduct: addProduct
}

return vm;

function addProduct(id, name, category) {
    products.push({id: id, name: name, category:category});
}
```

etc.